# Is there a good way of decoupling similar code obtained by inheriting the same interface in c#?

Tags: c#, oop, interface, polymorphism, decoupling

Let's say, in code, we have an IEnemy interface which has a method on it called Attack(). Let's also say that we have five enemies deriving from IEnemy interface. On three of these classes, we use the exact same implementation of the Attack method. In one of them, we also use the same code but with one or two lines of code changing somewhere in the method. And, in the last class, we still have the same implementation but with one or two lines of code added/removed somewhere in the method. Do you have any suggestion to decouple this code?

I've tried overriding the method which doesn't work in case if we change something in the middle of the method.
I've tried to use a delegate as a parameter which doesn't work when we want to change something somewhere else in the method.
I've tried to use extension methods for the interface for making a default implementation but two of the classes still have decoupled code.

```
interface IEnemy
{
    void Attack();
}

class Enemy1 : IEnemy
{
    public void Attack()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("This is an enemy");
        Console.WriteLine("Enemy is jumping");
        Console.WriteLine("Enemy is attacking");
    }
}

class Enemy2 : IEnemy
{
    public void Attack()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("This is an enemy");
        Console.WriteLine("Enemy is jumping");
        Console.WriteLine("Enemy is attacking");
    }
}

class Enemy3 : IEnemy
{
    public void Attack()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("This is an enemy");
        Console.WriteLine("Enemy is jumping");
        Console.WriteLine("Enemy is attacking");
    }
}

//Let's say this enemy is not capable of jumping, so we want to remove the code that says enemy is jumping.
class Enemy4 : IEnemy
{
    public void Attack()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("This is an enemy");
        Console.WriteLine("Enemy is attacking");
    }
}

//Let's say this is the boss and instead of jumping, it will roar.
//So we want to change the code that says enemy is jumping to enemy is roaring.
class Enemy5 : IEnemy
{
    public void Attack()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("This is an enemy");
        Console.WriteLine("Enemy is roaring");
        Console.WriteLine("Enemy is attacking");
    }
}
```

Comment: You should use a base class instead with a `virtual` implementation that can be overridden if required, or use the default base-class implementation.

Comment: But when I want to change something in the middle of the method, I can't change it without decoupling so I'll still have to write the implementation again with the modifications, won't I?

Comment: @HeroOfSkies in your case not directly even with abstract, But if the enemy can jump or roar or whatever, it has to be a generic boolean property available to the parent class. Where the parent class can then display the proper message with an if / else statement.

Comment: @Franck Thanks for the answer, and for the suggestion too :)

Comment: You can isolate jumping, attacking, and roaring into their own classes, and `IEnemy` can depend on them via some abstraction. That way instead of using inheritance, each enemy is just a composition of various behaviours.

Comment: @ScottHannen That's actually a great idea, thanks! Is it possible for you to post this as an answer, preferably with some code exemples? I think this could be the answer that I'm looking for

Comment: I put it as a comment because my input is a little bit vague.

Comment: Alright, thanks anyway :)

Comment: Why use an interface instead of a base class? In this case, default implementation for interface methods could help you (coming in C# soon). I would suggest breaking `Attack` up and delegating the steps back - e.g. `Attack() => { AttackID(); AttackSignal(); AttackAttack(); }` then `AttackSignal()` would be overridden as needed.

Comment: you can create an abstract base class, put the common method in it and have the 3 classes extend the ABC. as others have said, you can have all of them derive from the ABC and override the method. and have everyone implementing the interface.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would replace the interface with an abstract base class with default implementations, and then break up the `Attack` method into separate overridable steps. I made `Attack` virtual for enemies that have totally their own attack pattern.

```
abstract class BaseEnemy {
    public virtual void Attack() {
        AttackIdentify();
        AttackSignal();
        AttackAttack();
    }

    protected virtual void AttackIdentify() {
        Console.WriteLine("This is an enemy");
    }

    protected virtual void AttackSignal() {
        Console.WriteLine("Enemy is jumping");
    }

    protected virtual void AttackAttack() {
        Console.WriteLine("Enemy is attacking");
    }
}

class Enemy1 : BaseEnemy {
    protected override void AttackIdentify() {
        Console.WriteLine("This is an enemy 1");
    }
}

class Enemy2 : BaseEnemy {
}

class Enemy3 : BaseEnemy {
    protected override void AttackIdentify() {
        Console.WriteLine("This is an enemy 3");
    }
}

//Let's say this enemy is not capable of jumping, so we want to remove the code that says enemy is jumping.
class Enemy4 : BaseEnemy {
    protected override void AttackSignal() { }
}

//Let's say this is the boss and instead of jumping, it will roar.
//So we want to change the code that says enemy is jumping to enemy is roaring.
class Enemy5 : BaseEnemy {
    protected override void AttackSignal() {
        Console.WriteLine("Enemy is roaring");
    }
}
```

If you still need the interface `IEnemy`, you can have `BaseEnemy` implement it.

Comment: This is nice because you essentially establish an attack template to follow with the ability to customize it.

Comment: I also thought about this pattern but it seemed like there is way too much writing so I thought I was over complicating things but this is still the best I can find. Thanks :)

Comment: @HeroOfSkies With the abstract base class, you only write extra code when you need to - how is this too much writing to you? Look at `Enemy2`...

Comment: @HeroOfSkies If you are convinced... :) - not trying to argue, just trying to understand your POV...

Comment: Just a quick note: the `AttackIdentify`, `AttackSignal` and `AttackAttack` should be `protected`, not `public`.

Comment: It's also possible to use the builder pattern to build an instance of an `Attack` class. Hope I'll get around to write a quick sample tomorrow

Comment: Well, after starting to work on an example, the idea I had is an overkill. This is a better option.

Answer (score 0):

Here a basic example of the abstract class version of it.

```
public abstract class Enemy
{
    public bool CanJump { get; set; } = false;
    public bool CanRoar { get; set; } = false;
    public bool CanAttack { get; set; } = false;

    public virtual void Attack()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("This is an enemy");

        if (CanJump)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Enemy is jumping");
        }

        if (CanRoar)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Enemy is roaring");
        }

        if (CanAttack)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Enemy is attacking");
        }
    }
}

public class Enemy1 : Enemy
{
    public Enemy1()
    {
        CanJump = true;
        CanRoar = true;
    }
}

public class Enemy2 : Enemy
{
    public Enemy2()
    {
        CanRoar = true;
        CanAttack = true;
    }
}

public class Enemy3 : Enemy
{
    public Enemy3()
    {
        CanRoar = true;
        CanAttack = true;
    }

    public override void Attack()
    {
        base.Attack();

        Console.WriteLine("Custom thing");
    }
}
```

You will notice that `Enemy1` and `Enemy2` work the same way but set different properties which when you call the `Attack` method will display accordingly. The interesting part i want you to pay attention is the `Enemy3` class which override the method. This is doable by making the method `Virtual` in the `Enemy` abstract class.

This override allow to still call the base class method `Attack` in the class `Enemy` PLUS it also display a custom value. So it is very flexible.

Note that this works perfectly for the example provided but by going by the name of your class i can easily assume what the real project is and this is not the proper way to do it. You shouldn't create a different class for each enemy but that is out of the scope of the question.

Comment: I don't think it is a good idea to put `if` logic in the base `Attack` method. You should be delegating that to the specific Enemy.

Comment: This seems pretty inflexible to me. You have no choice but to keep forcing all enemies to carry around functionality they may not care about and even if they did, they're bound to the execution order the base determines which they might not want. Having the base provide a set of methods for an attack *lifecycle* that each can provide custom actions for might be better.

Comment: @ChiefTwoPencils It is not perfectly flexible. The goal was to make it flexible for his format. In the best case scenario you wouldn't have a class for each enemy but instead a single one with a collection of actions that is customized through a factory class. I just tried to keep as much as possible his original format to not confuse that new developper.

Comment: @Franck I've actually never thought about factories. I'm not that new in development(even though I haven't really used design patterns until recently) so could you explain how I could do it with a factory?